Creating a uniform triangle texture

I'm trying to create this lance, using the model i have from the manufactuer. Would this dual texture be possible with what i have. I can't easily split the object into the required separate surfaces.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

there are two options: 1. Create a texture with black and white triangles, and apply it to the roughness parameter of the material (or even different materials). Another option is to physically divide the mesh into triangles and apply a separate material to each. In both cases, the result will be something like this: https://ibb.co/XDDzYCN

That's great, thank you

@arachnoden That comment appears to be an answer. Please do post it as such, so the question will show marked as answered.

The easiest way is to download a black and white triangular pattern from the Internet, and use it as a factor when mixing rough and smooth shaders.

If for some reason this method is not suitable, then we create a ring with six vertices. We fill it with triangles, and remove the top vertex.

We create two materials, one smooth, the other rough.


We apply a smooth material to the entire object. Then we highlight the figure (which was once hexagonal) like this:

And apply rough material to selected surfaces (don't forget to click Assign)
Then we apply two "Arrays" modifiers to the result. The one on the X-axis - by 1, the one on the Y-axis - by 0.666666.

As a result, we have the same pattern.

 (Blender v 4.1.0)
